# How do I solve for x? $y=e^x+x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no clue really, I know that $x$ can be written as $\ln (e^x)$ and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Subtract $1$ from both sides & exponentiate each side 
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{y-1} =e^x e^{e^{x}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now recall the Lambert $W$ function is defined by $we^w=z$ gives $w=W(z)$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^x=W(e^{y-1})  \\
x=\ln(W(e^{y-1})). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I am not sure if that function is studied in algebra-precalc